# How to calculate the optimal number of serverss in a M/D/c queue?

Tags: stochastic-processes, queueing-theory, poisson-distribution

Assuming that the arrivals occur according to a Poisson process and that the time to process each arrival is fixed, how can the optimal number of servers 'c' be calculated such that the waiting time of each arrival and the numbers of 'c' can be kept as low as possible?

Should I approach this problem by taking different numbers of 'c', calculating the average waiting time for each number of 'c' and compare which combination of 'c' and the waiting time would be optimal?

I mean, to ensure a short waiting time, we could simply take a very high value for 'c' which is obviously not what we want.

Context: it concerns an assignment concerning a model describing a tunnel containing tollgates represented by 'c'. The arrivals are cars, and we want to keep the waiting time for the cars as low as possible, and use as less tollgates as possible as those are apparently fairly expensive.

Edit: I'm not so sure whether I've described the problem using the M/D/c queue correctly as I came to that conclusion just after a while of doing research on the internet.

Comment: What is the cost of an extra server or tollgate?  What is the cost of 1 car spending one unit of time queuing?  The ratio will determine the optimal $c$ (together with the rate of arrivals and service time).

Comment: Thank you a lot. Those questions sure did steer me in the right direction. I don't know the cost of an extra server or a car spending a certain time waiting yet (those will still have to be found out during the project), but now I know very well what I have to do to determine the optimal 'c', once those unknowns are known.